# General solution of ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

please what is the general solution of $$-(p(t)u')'+q(t)u=0$$ where $\displaystyle\frac{1}{p},\frac{1}{q}\in L^1((0,+\infty))$

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to solve this at all on your own?

Comment: my problem is how to do at first because i dont have that $p\in C^1$ but $\frac{1}{p}\in L^1$

Comment: Without knowing $p$ is $C^1$ and $q$ is $C^0$, you need to rephrase the problem as $p(t) u'(t) - p(0) u'(0) = \int_0^t q(t) u(t)$.

Comment: @Ian how to continu after that ? please